# Create Subplots in with a unique Figure Handle Python

Tags: python

I really dont know what i am doing wrong.

I am trying to create a sub plot in a figure window.

The code i have so far is as follows:-

```
 Wall_Height_Figure = pyplot.figure("Wall Height") # Wall_Height_Figure is the name of the container and Wall Height is the title name 
    
(Plot_A, Plot_B, Plot_C, Plot_D) = Wall_Height_Figure.subplots(2, 2) # within the figure window i want to create a 2 by 2 sub plot
       
Plot_A[0,0].plot(x_data, y_data_one)
Plot_B[0,1].plot(x_data, y_data_two)
Plot_C[1,0].plot(x_data, y_data_three)
Plot_D[1,1].plot(x_data, y_data_four)
```

This code does not work but i do not know why?

The error i get is as follows:-

```
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 2)
```

I want to create a figure window called Wall_Height_Figure titled Wall Height.

I then want to create 4 x subplots in a 2 x 2 grid inside my Wall_Height_Figure.

I then want to display my plots using co-ordinates i.e. [0,1] for Plot B which to me means plot in subplot in row 0 column 1.

But this does not work what am i doing wrong??

Can any one help?

Thank you.

Comment: please check the values returned by ```Wall_Height_Figure.subplots(2, 2)```.  As the error states, it's returning two items.

Comment: Hi ewong thank you for the reply. the value returned by Wall_Height_Figure.subplots(2, 2) is a 2 x 2 Array Object.

Comment: Hi ewong thank you for the reply. the value returned by Wall_Height_Figure.subplots(2, 2) is a 2 x 2 Array Object. So i am assigning (Plot_A, Plot_B, Plot_C, Plot_D)  into a 2D array. So i need to convert (Plot_A, Plot_B, Plot_C, Plot_D)  into a 2D array, if this is correct then how would i do this?